# inaccessible due to its protection level error in a code from a Microsoft Tutorial

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-services

The following code from an [Official Microsoft Azure tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/quickstarts/csharp) is giving the following error message at the first line:

```
ITextAnalyticsAPI client = new TextAnalyticsAPI();
```

> `TextAnalyticsAPI.TextAnalyticsAPI(param DelegatingHandler[])`  is inaccessible due to its protection level

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.TextAnalytics;
using Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.TextAnalytics.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create a client.
            ITextAnalyticsAPI client = new TextAnalyticsAPI();
            client.AzureRegion = AzureRegions.Westus;
            client.SubscriptionKey = "ENTER KEY HERE";

            Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

            // Extracting language
            Console.WriteLine("===== LANGUAGE EXTRACTION ======");

            LanguageBatchResult result = client.DetectLanguage(
                    new BatchInput(
                        new List<Input>()
                        {
                          new Input("1", "This is a document written in English."),
                          new Input("2", "Este es un document escrito en Español."),
                          new Input("3", "这是一个用中文写的文件")
                        }));

            // Printing language results.
            foreach (var document in result.Documents)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Document ID: {0} , Language: {1}", document.Id, document.DetectedLanguages[0].Name);
            }

            // Getting key-phrases
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n===== KEY-PHRASE EXTRACTION ======");

            KeyPhraseBatchResult result2 = client.KeyPhrases(
                    new MultiLanguageBatchInput(
                        new List<MultiLanguageInput>()
                        {
                          new MultiLanguageInput("ja", "1", "猫は幸せ"),
                          new MultiLanguageInput("de", "2", "Fahrt nach Stuttgart und dann zum Hotel zu Fu."),
                          new MultiLanguageInput("en", "3", "My cat is stiff as a rock."),
                          new MultiLanguageInput("es", "4", "A mi me encanta el fútbol!")
                        }));


            // Printing keyphrases
            foreach (var document in result2.Documents)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Document ID: {0} ", document.Id);

                Console.WriteLine("\t Key phrases:");

                foreach (string keyphrase in document.KeyPhrases)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t\t" + keyphrase);
                }
            }

            // Extracting sentiment
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n===== SENTIMENT ANALYSIS ======");

            SentimentBatchResult result3 = client.Sentiment(
                    new MultiLanguageBatchInput(
                        new List<MultiLanguageInput>()
                        {
                          new MultiLanguageInput("en", "0", "I had the best day of my life."),
                          new MultiLanguageInput("en", "1", "This was a waste of my time. The speaker put me to sleep."),
                          new MultiLanguageInput("es", "2", "No tengo dinero ni nada que dar..."),
                          new MultiLanguageInput("it", "3", "L'hotel veneziano era meraviglioso. È un bellissimo pezzo di architettura."),
                        }));


            // Printing sentiment results
            foreach (var document in result3.Documents)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Document ID: {0} , Sentiment Score: {1:0.00}", document.Id, document.Score);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I am using the package from here that says it was released yesterday. So, I assume it must be the latest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, most likely, that you got [the wrong package version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language).

The post is from `09-20-2017` and the package's `1.0.0` preview version is from `09-19-2017`.
Yet the latest version of the package is the `1.0.1` which was released yesterday and you most likely installed.

A minor upgrade shouldn't have breaking changes, but...

Comment: Thank you for helping me resolve the issue. Your guess was correct. After I uninstalled the latest version and installed the previous version `1.0.0` it worked. For benefits of other: I first ran `UnInstall-Package Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language -Version 1.0.1-preview` and then `Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language -Version 1.0.0-preview`